# is it possible to create an invisible xaml command always set to true?

Tags: c#, xaml, icommand

I am working with a window and I would like to create a command that is invisible (or virtual, I am not sure about how it is called) and always checks itself (always true during runtime). This way I could write a script code in C# that I can control with a timer.

so far I only find the usual commands in xaml for normal events for example:

`<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="N" Command="{Binding NewCommandFile}" />`.

Is it even possible to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Why not just have the timer run the code you want to run directly? or do you want to call the code both from a timer and a command-binding?

Comment: I want to call the code from a command binding. Just like in a normal command binding like the one I show if that happens, i can execute a script

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but you can create a custom command. For example, a command that runs an arbitrary delegate:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action execute;
    public DelegateCommand(Action execute) => this.execute = execute;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => execute();

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add{} remove{}}
}
```

In your code behind file you would write

```
public ICommand MyCommand{ get; }
public MyViewModel(){
    MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyMethod);
}
public void MyMethod(){
     // Do whatever
}
```

And bind with

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="N" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />.
```

Comment: yes, thank you very much, I will explore this idea!

Comment: the example helps but I want to virtually set it to true based on some events and not based on the user that clicks a button. basically the events act as a virtual user

Comment: @josh.h your usage of 'virtual' is confusing, it is usually used to refer to virtual methods, and I think that is not what you mean. The example shows how to connect a wpf button to a method thru a command, if you want to call the method some other way, just call it. If you intend to do some UI-automation framework to click buttons I suggest you check how other such tools do this.

Comment: sorry for my poor choice of words. what I meant is to create a command that executes itself (as if some non person user is also present and clicks on a button). and that would be done periodically. I am wondering if this is possible to do with a wpf button through a non-conventional command

Comment: @josh.h use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) whenever you want to do something periodically. Attach `MyMethod` to the timer event.

Comment: this is not my problem, my problem is there are other (physical) buttons in the interface , and a normal button would be executed by the user (clicking on it). I am asking about the non-existent non-user command that I want to click internally. It s the order of "clicking" that I want to somehow get

Comment: @josh.h Do you mean the button animation for a click?

Comment: No. I mean the order that triggers the method Execute itself. that´s why I was wondering if it had to be done in the xaml with a Command that´s always set to true....